# Setting default values in API Gateway request validation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

Is it possible to declare a default value in the model of a api gateway endpoint? I'm trying to, like that:

```
 1 {
  2   "type": "object",
  3   "required": ["name"],
  4   "properties": {
  5     "name": {
  6       "type": "string",
  7       "default": "My Name"
  8     }
  9   }
 10 }
```

But it doesn't work at all. If I don't pass the name, the API Gateway will return an error saying that the body is not valid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html):

> The payload can have a data model according to the [JSON schema draft 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04).

JSON schema draft 4 doesn't define a way to specify a default value. So my guess is no, it's not possible to do this using an input model.

If you really want to do this in API Gateway layer then perhaps you should explore the input mapping template. "A mapping template is a script expressed in Velocity Template Language (VTL)". VTL seems to have much better capability.

IMHO its a bad idea. I would rather just do this in backend.

Comment: I can confirm this. `default` has been added since draft 4, but has no defined behaviour. Any use of `default` is validator or application specific. We're looking to clarify this at some point before moving beyond draft status.

Comment: @Relequestual still I can't get the default value defined in the schema from the backend. I've defined a name attribute and set the default value as "myName" and sent a request without the name attribute, when I print the name within the lambda function I am receiving the empty value. Is this a valid behaviour ?

Comment: The `default` keyword is still an annotation only. Any behaviour that modifies the instance data (data being validated) is implementation/application specific. Annotations, if collected by the implementation (which is not required), may be used by downstream applications to do other things, such as fill in default values. I do not believe AWS provides annotations for downstream applications.